# How to run a process and find how much memory it uses?

Tags: command-line, process, memory

I regularly use `time` to find out how long a process takes. Is there an equivalent command for memory? The usual ways to find out how much memory a process takes (`ps`,`/proc/meminfo`, etc.) work fine for a long-running process, but I don't know of anything that works like `time` does, for a command run from the command line. I'm imaging something like "size", except that includes the stack and heap:

```
% mem python myscript.py
   text    data    heap 
3135006  570928  115528
```

Comment: Yes indeed, it is. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: You should be able to click the "Yes, this answered my question!" button to mark this one as a duplicate, then.  Glad I could help.  :)

Comment: I don't see where to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Below stuff may help :

```
var=$(pgrep process_name_here);
top -b -p "$var" | awk -v var=$var '$1~var{print $10}'
```

You might even think of writing a script and passing the process name as argument

**Note:** This solution **will not** work if you change the default layout for the top command. In that case you need to replace $10 with appropriate field number